# Is it possible to declare non enumerable property on javascript constructor?

Tags: javascript

I need to know if is possible to make instances of a javascript class that has non-enumerable attributes, for example

```
// Constructor
function MyClass(a) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, '_number', {
        enumerable: false
    });
    this.number = a; // Call setter for '_number'
}

// Getters and setters for '_number'
Object.defineProperty(MyClass.prototype, 'number', {
   get: function() {
       return this._number;
   },
   set: function(n) {
       // Validate 'n' here
       this._number = n;
   }
});
```

What I wanted this code to do is to define the property `_number` on any instance of `MyClass`, making it not enumerable so that instance private variables such as `_number` wouldn't be listed in, suppose, a `for in` structure. You would use the `number` getter/setter to alter the private variable `_number`.

I have tried declaring the `_number` and `number` properties both inside the constructor and on `MyClass.prototype` with no success...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is fine, you just need to watch out for the other attribute values [which default to `false`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description):

```
function MyClass(a) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, '_number', {
        value: 0,          // better than `undefined`
        writable: true,    // important!
        enumerable: false, // could be omitted
        configurable: true // nice to have
    });
    this.number = a; // Call setter for '_number'
}

// Getters and setters for '_number'
Object.defineProperty(MyClass.prototype, 'number', {
   get: function() {
       return this._number;
   },
   set: function(n) {
       // Validate 'n' here
       this._number = n;
   },
   enumerable: true,  // to get `.number` enumerated in the loop
   configurable: true // nice to have
});
```

Comment: If interpret Question correctly, could not OP simply set the `value` of `number` to `a` within `Object.defineProerty()` at `MyClass`?

Comment: Yeah, he could, but it sounds like he does want to run the (destined) validation logic from the setter in the constructor as well. `0` would be the default value if the validation fails and the instance is created nonetheless.